# Data frame of matrices

Tags: r

I would like to create list of matrices and vectors.
df[matrix[n:m], "Label"]
What would be the command to use to do that assuming I have list of matrices and list of labels separately?

I am creating the matrices by reading csv files and I would like to label each file.

```
B = matrix( c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=3, ncol=2)
df <- list(B, c("label"))
C = matrix( c(3, 7, 2, 1, 6, 7), nrow=3, ncol=2)
df <- list(C, c("label1"))  //Not the expected results
```

How I add C matrix to df so I will have a list with 2 col and 2 rows? 
Something like this:

```
         [,1]    [,2]
[1,]    B[3:2]  "label"
[2,]    C[3:2]  "label1"  
[3,]    D[3:2]  "label2"
```

Comment: Could you add a simple example of the matrixes and labels. You could use the mtcars dataset to make it reproducible. Also, perhaps you could give an example of the preferred output.

Comment: I add explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is a named list sufficient?

Comment: Tried it but was not able to work with it. In general I am trying to use knn on the matrixes.

Comment: Because if you only need a label, and not other meta information, that seems like the preferred/easiest way to go

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to use a named list:

```
matrices <- list()
matrices[["label1"]] <- matrix( c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=3, ncol=2)
matrices$label2 <- matrix( c(3, 7, 2, 1, 6, 7), nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

Then, you could use `lapply` to map a function (e.g. knn) over all the matrices. This is an easier solution then using a data frame if you have only one piece of meta data.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to use it and get back to you.

Comment: What about appending another matrices to the list? Any elegant way to do it?

Comment: Use `matrices[[length(matrices)+1]] <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 2)` or give it a name with `matrices[["name"]]`